# Как запретить выполнение функции если курсор над элементом побыл недостаточно долго?

Tags: javascript

Мои тщетные попытки:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

items.forEach(item => {
  item.dataset.t1 = 0;
  item.dataset.t2 = 0;
  item.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseEnterHandler);
  item.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeaveHandler);
})

function mouseEnterHandler({target}) {
  target.dataset.t1 = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (target.dataset.t1 - target.dataset.t2 > 0)
      doSomethnig(target);
  }, 1000);
}

function mouseLeaveHandler({target}) {
  target.dataset.t2 = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
}

function doSomethnig(el) {
  el.classList.toggle('tomato');
}
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tomato {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Если быстро наводить и убирать курсор с элемента, а затем навести и задержать, это чудо перестаёт корректно работать.

Comment: У вас квант - 1 сек, попробуйте уменьшить квант, хотя бы 1/4 сек (250) или 100 в таймер поставить.

Comment: @nick_n_a 100 и 250 слишком мало. Мне не нужно триггерить функцию если я просто хочу добраться, например, до последнего элемента проведя мышкой в неспешном темпе по всем остальным.

Comment: @hu-fo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207119/enable-hover-event-after-certain-time

Answer (score 4):

Спасибо [grime](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/365726/grime) за комментарий. Дельце распутано.

Ну и код [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207382/12226424) на ванильном js:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

var setTimeoutConst;
items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseEnterHandler);
  item.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeaveHandler);
})

function mouseEnterHandler({target}) {
  setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(() => doSomethnig(target), 1000);
}

function mouseLeaveHandler({targe}) {
  clearInterval(setTimeoutConst);
}

function doSomethnig(el) {
  el.classList.toggle('tomato');
}
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tomato {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```